# Push function passing empty objects into array after constructor function Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am learning Vue JS and ran into a particular issue while trying to populate an array with objects using a constructor function and the push function. In Vue JS, the push method adds a blank object into the array instead of the one created by the constructor. JS fiddle below.

I know in conventional javascript the code below would work fine, can anyone explain why Vue JS is interpreting the same code differently.

```
function node (){
  this.x = Math.random();
  this.y = Math.random();
}

let nodes = [];
nodes.push(new node());
console.log(nodes);
```

**JS Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/ex080/t690v9pu/

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="generate">Generate Object</button>
  <li v-for="node in nodes">
    {{node.num}}
  </li>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    nodes: []
  },
  methods: {
    node() {
        num = Math.random();
        console.log(num);
      },
      generate() {
        this.nodes.push(new this.node());
      }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not storing a reference to `num` anywhere. Try returning an object from the node method:

```
 return {num:  Math.random()}
```

Edit:

Using `new` creates an object and with it a context:

```
function node (){
  // 'this' refers to the instance of the node object
  // it keeps a reference to the properties x and y
  this.x = Math.random();
  this.y = Math.random();
}
```

Declaring the method `node()` however is a function and not constructing an object.

```
node() {
    // 'num' is declared and is accessible only within the scope of the function
    // it is a candidate for garbage collection as soon as the function completes.
    num = Math.random();
    console.log(num);
},
```

The way I showed you returning the object, for the sake of demonstration, achieves the same as using `new node()` from your first example.

Comment: that seems to work, but can you explain why the constructor function works in traditional javascript without the `return` and why exactly I need it in the Vue JS version?

Comment: Updated my answer hopefully that helps explain the differences

Comment: This could have been avoid if you would have added the 'use strict' mode to your java-script file. its one of the good practice which saves a lot of time